# Possible to use a field within a query in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I want to query all events that are going on right now. Each `events` record has `at` and `minutes` fields for the time range of the event. I might query the `events` table like this:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE at >= NOW() - INTERVAL '2 hours' AND at <= NOW()
```

This assumes the event is 2 hours long. But I don't know that. The actual length is stored in the `minutes` field. How can I use that field in my query? Or is there a better mechanism for me? I've unsuccessfully tried things like this:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE at >= NOW() - INTERVAL minutes ' minutes' AND at <= NOW()
```

One little caveat is that performance does matter, somewhat. There is a large number of events in our database and that is growing fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
WHERE at >= NOW() - minute * INTERVAL '1 minute' AND at <= NOW()
```

The Postgres documentation page has similar examples: [Date/Time Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html)

The above is not going to be very efficient but you could add an index on `at + minute * INTERVAL '1 minute'` and then modify the query condition:

```
WHERE at <= NOW() AND (at + minute * INTERVAL '1 minute') >= NOW()
```

But it would probably be better if you used a gist index on the range (from when the event starts until it finishes), with something like this:

```
CREATE INDEX event_start_end_idx ON events 
  USING gist (tsrange(at, at + minute * INTERVAL '1 minute'));
```

and then use the "contains" (`@>`) range operator:

```
WHERE tsrange(at, at + minute * INTERVAL '1 minute'))  @>  NOW()
```

Comment: excellent! now is this going to always have to scan every single row? Seems like it. Any way to do this without scanning every row?

Comment: I think the `at <= NOW()` will be able to be used if there is an index on `at` (so maybe not a full table scan if you have data with future dates). If (as expected) all data are in the past, you could create an index on an expression. Editing the answer.